# How do I plot the derivative of a set of points in 3D?

Tags: plotting, calculus-and-analysis

I have a set of points like this: P = {{$x_1$,$y_1$,$f(x_1,y_1)$},{$x_2$,$y_2$,$f(x_2,y_2)$},...,{$x_n$,$y_n$,$f(x_n,y_n)$}}.

I want to plot them and also plot the derivative of that graph. How can I do this with Mathematica? Is there a simple way in Mathematica?

Comment: You can plot the points with `ListPointPlot[P]`, although user variables should not begin with a capital.  I don't know what you mean by "the derivative" in this context.

Comment: Derivative of what graph with respect to what?

Comment: If you have the function `f` only on discrete points, then you cannot simply derive them. What you need is some kind of numerical scheme and Mathematica has a lot of them built-in. One way is to interpolate your points by a smooth function and use the derivative of the interpolation function. If your points `{x,y}` are not on a grid, it is a bit trickier, but can be accomplished as well. Is it possible that you provide your points (or a list of example points)?

Comment: @thedude and Alan, i have a large set of numerical values of the form ($x_i$,$y_i$,$f(x_i,y_i)$), where $x_i$ and $y_i$ are the independent variables and $f(x_i,y_i)$ depends on the both $x_i$ & $y_i$. I got its 3D plot through ListPlot3D now i want to plot the derivative of this 3D plot? Probably a partial derivative i think?

Comment: @halirutan Since i have a big data, so i give you the points for example: {{0., 0.384609, 0.999965, -0.399952, 0.0333553, -0.430301}, {0.587785,
   0.853728, 0.804087, -0.862295, 0.614443, -0.878706}, {0.951057, 
  0.996752, 0.301074, -0.99527, 0.960835, -0.991475}, {0.951057, 
  0.75905, -0.316938, -0.748085, 0.94022, -0.725534}, {0.587785, 
  0.231417, -0.813891, -0.215158, 
  0.560473, -0.182464}, {0., -0.384609, -0.999965, 
  0.399952, -0.0333553, 0.430301}}

Comment: @Usman But you realize, that the points you gave as examples lie on a grid, while your general form of `P` doesn't require this. Anyway, for the examples `pts` you could use `ip = ListInterpolation[pts]; dfdy=Derivative[1, 0][ip]` to construct an interpolating function for the first partial derivative..

Comment: The example data can be almost *exactly* fit to an analytic function,  `Sin[0.6 y - 0.2 - 0.8 x + 0.4 x^2 ]` which you can then differentiate readily. I don't know how useful it would be to see how to get that if your real data doesn't have such a nice form.

Comment: @halirutan, Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Since you don't give an example of `P`, I will use the following data:

```
data = Flatten[
    Table[{x, y, Sin[x y]}, {x, 0, 5, .1}, {y, 0, 5, .1}],
    1
];
```

The data is on a structured grid, meaning there is data for every point on a rectangular mesh. Hence, we can just use Interpolation:

```
if = Interpolation[data]
```

> InterpolatingFunction[{{0., 5.}, {0., 5.}}, <>]

Now, if we want to plot the `x` derivative, we can just differentiate the [`InterpolatingFunction`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/InterpolatingFunction):

```
dx = Derivative[1, 0][if]
```

> InterpolatingFunction[{{0., 5.}, {0., 5.}}, <>]

We see that the result is another [`InterpolatingFunction`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/InterpolatingFunction). Plotting the [`InterpolatingFunction`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/InterpolatingFunction) is simple:

```
Plot3D[dx[x, y], {x, 0, 5}, {y, 0, 5}]
```

[image]

Since we constructed the data using `Sin[x y]`, we know that the `x` derivative is simply `y Cos[x y]`. Let's compare:

```
Plot3D[y Cos[x y], {x, 0, 5}, {y, 0, 5}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. This is quite helpful.